# What BGM is playing in Iron-Blooded Orphans season 2 episode 16&23?

Tags: music, gundam-iron-blooded-orphans

In *Mobile Suit Gundam: Iron-Blooded Orphans* Episode 41 (or Season 2 Episode 16) - "Natural for a Human", there is an insert song/BGM playing at 20:22, but the main theme of the song starts around 22:57.

The same song plays in Season 2 Episode 23, starting at 19:02 until 19:57.

What is this song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Our Home*, the 17th track of *Gundam Iron-Blooded Orphan OST II* album.  [YouTube link](https://youtu.be/X55tGnMCpyM)

Comment: Thank you! BGM always takes a while I guess. You just made my day. Nice way to start 2021.

Answer (score -1):

Freesia by URU

^ FYI it says on myanimelist at Ending Theme section
https://myanimelist.net/anime/33051/Mobile_Suit_Gundam__Iron-Blooded_Orphans_2nd_Season

Comment: Thanks, but that is an ending song, not the song that starts at 20:22 which is completely different.